# How can I extend 2 classes in Java? I need to extend JFrame plus another class

Tags: jframe, extend

I have created a class called `Gui`. It needs to extend `JFrame` and another class called `StudentDatabase`.

**How can I do it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend more than one class in Java.

Instead of using inheritance use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) (extend JFrame and have a member of class StudentDatabase in your class GUI).

Pass invocations of methods in GUI to its member StudentDatabase and voila...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. In C++ you can do this. In Java you can implement multiple "interfaces", but you'll have to rewrite the implementations of all functions in those interfaces in your class.